# Как изменить стиль текста при нажатии на него Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Как мне обратиться к стилю текста с помощью GetComponent, чтобы при нажатии на него он становился жирным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так.
Создаете скрипт, который вешаете на Ваш `Text`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeTextColorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void ChangeTextStyle()
    {
        GetComponent<Text>().text = "<b>"+GetComponent<Text>().text+"</b>";
    }  
}
```

Добавляете компонент `Button` и в `onClick` в `Inspector` указываете этот текст и выбираете функцию `ChangeTextStyle()`.

Тогда при нажатии на Ваш текст его стиль изменится на жирный. За "жирность" в этом случае отвечают теги для `rich`-текста `<b></b>`, поэтому в `Inspector` у текста также должна стоять галочка `Rich Text`

Answer (score 1):

Я в данном случае не согласен с первым ответом Анастасии, так как в ее случае нам нужно:

- Дважды обращаться к компоненту
- Работать со строками
- Применять теги rich-текста

А **зачем**, если в Unity даже у обычного [Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) (не нужен никакой [TextMeshPro](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html)) есть такой простейший параметр как [FontStyle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FontStyle.html)!

Его можно изменять *напрямую* из скрипта в также в *одну* строку, но *без* двойного обращения к геткомпоненту, *без* работы со строками, *без* необходимости проверять включен там этот RichText или нет (по умолчанию он вроде включен?):

```
public void ChangeTextStyle()
{
    GetComponent<Text>().fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
}
```

FontStyle - это enum, который содержит 4 возможных значения: Bold (жирный), Italic (Курсив), BoldAndItalic (жирный курсив), Normal (обычный текст).

> GetComponent(), кстати, можно закэшировать в отдельную переменную, чтобы каждый раз к нему не обращаться, хотя не думаю, что так часто нужно будет менять стиль шрифта.

Comment: Вам не следует изменять код по содержанию при редактировании чужих ответов или вопросов. Форматирование, отступы - пожалуйста, в некоторых случаях можно юзинги выкинуть, но другие изменения вносить крайне не рекомендуется. Представьте, пришел я к вам в ответ и переписал ваш код, как мне нравится, вам приятно будет?

Comment: Если же у вас есть замечания к автору, лучше напишите их в комментарий, пусть автор сам поправит.

Comment: @aepot Забавно. "Можно юзинги выкинуть" - я их и выкинул. Код должен быть "минимальным, воспроизводимым". Зачем, только, пожалуйста, конкретно, зачем: ТС нужен using System, using UnityEngine, которые вообще сами подключаются? Зачем ТС нужно название класса, если он 99% свой класс назовет по-другому? Зачем лишняя информация? Если в моем коде есть ошибки: пожалуйста, исправьте, я буду только рад! Может я опечатался, может нужно есть лучшие названия для функции, может вы добавите как кэшировать геткомпонент. Пожалуйста! Добавляйте. Это база знаний и здесь важны ответы, а не бзинги и классы.

Comment: К тому же в ответе Анастасии из всех 11 строк кода, что называется make sense - имеет значение, несет смысл, исключительно одна-единственная. Ну, ладно, максимум 3: еще функция и закрывающая скобка функции :)

Comment: Я оставила класс и юзинги из тех соображений, что даю ответ участнику, уровня знаний которого не знаю. Если бы я была новичком, я бы хотела знать, куда эту функцию деть и почему слово `Text` подчеркивается красным. Возможно, это действительно не нужно, но я посчитала, что не помешает. Что насчёт самой make sense строки, я предложила один вариант) Ваш вариант очень хороший, я за него проголосовала. Уверена, автор вопроса выберет то, что нужно :)

Comment: Что ж, если автор вопроса что-то не поймёт у меня, то сможет посмотреть полный код у вас :)